# How create a default web page for iis (server not found) compatible with all browsers

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net, iis

as you know we have a default web site for iis (windows server 2008 - r2) like below :

[image: iis default web page]

when you stop a web site that default web site loads in client's browser instead.
now i want to change that default web site for the purpose below :
please open the site below in all of your browsers(firefox - internet explorer - chrome - etc) :
[undefined domain(web site)](http://www.blabla__.com)
for examle in firefox we have `server not found` page like below :

[image: server not found - in firefox]

for IE we have this :

[image: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage]

and etc...
i have a web site in my vps(my site.com) that i stopped it in iis.
when a user opens it i want to show him/her server not page(ff) for example instead of that default iis web site.
i want to create a conditional single web page for that default iis web site that shows `server not found` page for firefox or `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` page for IE or etc...
as you see i added `asp.net with c#` and `php` languages into my tags.
so what is the best way for creating that specific conditional web site and how can i create it?
can i create that web site with html language only(using with jquery or javascript or not)(this is better) or should i use a server-side language like `asp.net with c#` or `php`?
i installed php in my own vps (windows server 2008-r2) and there is no problem about that language.

**EDIT**
my problem is how can i have a conditional single web page?
when a user opens my stopped web site in FF i want to show him/her `server not found` page for FF, also when a user opens my stopped web site in IE i want to show him/her `Internet Explorer cannot display that webpage` for IE and etc...

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you going to serve the page to the browser if the browser cannot find the server?

Comment: hi dear Sani, i have a web site that i stopped it in iis. when a user opens it i want to show him/her server not page(ff) for example instead of that default iis web site.

Comment: dear Sani, blabla web site just was an example for showing you server not found page. my site is different and i am talking about this, not blabla web site.

Comment: please vote me up, i edit my q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a specific page when you have taken down your web site then just create another web site (on the same port, i.e. 80) that you start when the first is is stopped. In the second website you have a single page (i.e. Default.html, index.html, etc) which displays the information you want.

```
Main Site (Stopped)
Temporary Site (Started)
```

When you then start your main site again you just stop the temporary site.

**Edit**

If you stop ALL websites then the browser will not find anything and will display the `server not found` message specific to the browser. All you need to do is make sure all websites are stopped.

Comment: dear Sani, did you consider on my problem? my problem is how can i have a conditional single web page? when a user opens my stopped web site in FF i want to show him/her server not found page for FF, also when a user opens my stopped web site in IE i want to show him/her Internet Explorer can not display that webpage for IE and etc...

Comment: The thing is that you don't need to do anything. If you stop your website then the browsers will automatically display the corresponding "server not found" message. You just need to make sure all web sites on that port are stopped. If you want to display some other information then you need to start another web site on the same port. To determine which browser is used you can look at the USER AGENT in the headers.

Comment: but when i stop a web site in iis that green page loads instead of "server not found".

Comment: Then you still have the default web site running. Stop that too.

Comment: i stopped default web site too, but FireFox shows this page instead of regular "server not found" page -> http://up.khoone.org/up/1/nce1i7t1bcjwsan9b7cx.png

Comment: Then you can stop the IIS service alltogether.

Comment: i have many web sites in my iis and i cant completely stop it. do you know man? i want to hide that stopped web site from a user to know that i have stopped that web site in iis or not. i want that user to think that web site does not exist. also creating that single page is a nice try for me. thanks for the help...